# Unable to get the correct index of node that was clicked in d3 and update the JSON at that location

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In a collapsible tree diagram https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 I want to make a server call to receive additional children and append them to the existing JSON I have on load.

I am able to do this on click, but when I receive the JSON back how do I reliably get the correct index of the node that was clicked and update the JSON at that point it was clicked.

The depth of the children in the JSON is directly associated with function(d) { return d.depth }
but the index of which child was clicked at that depth seems to be the issue.

On the surface it seems simple enough and you would use the index given back by function(i) in d3, but it changes based on which nodes are open and closed. (open and close a few nodes in the pen and watch it update)

Is there some sort of find or another index feature in d3 I can leverage?

```
depth: 2 = children.children
```

how do I get the x's

```
root.children[x].children[x].children = childArray;
```

In the example there's only one layer of children, but this needs to work recursively so every node can be clicked to access more data.

Full Example is here (Line 264): 
http://codepen.io/pjbrof/pen/kXzGpd

```
root.children[0].children[0].children = childArray;
update(root);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the index passed to any D3 accessor function is always it's index in the DOM, relative to it's parent: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/73

The workaround I've used for this scenario is to implement in the click-event either an object lookup or an array filter, matching on a unique ID.